# How to use less files in Backbone project with Browserify?

Tags: backbone.js, less, browserify

```
 var $ = require('jquery')(window);
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;

var header = require('templates/header.hbs');
require('../../styles/main.less');
require('../../../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less');
require('../../../bower_components/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less');

  var headerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#mainheader'),
    render: function(){

      var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile( header );
      // Append our compiled template to this Views "el"
      this.$el.append( compiledTemplate );
    }
  });

module.exports = new headerView();
```

I am trying to include less files in Backbone project with browserify.

When i am creating the bundle.js file i get the following error:

[image]

Comment: you will possible need https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lessify

Comment: I have already added it

Comment: how does font-awesome.less look around line 5-6?

Comment: its not detecting the @import statements